# DisplayPort, Intel 5500, MST: Can I daisy chain 2 x 2560x1440 and 1x 1920x1080 displays?

Tags: display, displayport, laptop-display, daisychaining, mst

I have a Thinkpad T450s laptop. It comes with Intel 5500 graphics and  a displayport 1.2 (don't think it's 1.3).

I'm trying to figure out if I can add 2 screens @ 2560x1440 and retain the laptop internal screen @ 1920x1080. Ideally I would like to use two very good IPS external panels @ 2560x1440 or above and retain the laptop IPS panel to place at the top with a stand. I wanted to make sure first I can run such configuration.

Is there any calculator around for these things?

Sources so far on DP:

http://multimonitorcomputer.com/solved/displayport-daisy-chaining-of-3-or-4-monitors-quick-guide.php

http://www.displayport.org/cables/driving-multiple-displays-from-a-single-displayport-output/

About intel GMA I've found this:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/quick-reference-guide-to-intel-processor-graphics

from what I understood with a U processor the limit is 3840 x 2160 @ 60 Hz but that's probably a single display... I didn't figure out for multiple screens.

2 should be ok to connect to a single DP (Lenovo even makes an adapter for this purpose), I need only to know which max resolution each and if I can retain the HD laptop screen.